# Trouble using async function to download Files in NodeJS (using pipe)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

**DEVELOPER LEVEL -** beginner
Have recently started programming. Only Familiar with HTM/CSS/JS & NodeJS.
Find it very hard in the case of `async` and `Promises()`.

I'm using this ↓ code to automatically Download files, inside another `async` function.

How do I change this code in a way, so it returns something (a Promise maybe),
 and when I use it inside another `async` function( with `await` ), it waits for it to finish. 
[In other words - *waits for the download to finish, before moving on*]

**CODE -** [LINK TO CODE ON JSFIDLLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qyraz2j4/)

```js
// download function //
var downloadFile = async (uri, filename, callback) => {
    request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {

        console.log('\n', 'Downloading File');
        request(uri)
            .on('error', error => { res.status(502).send(console.log(error.message)) })
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${filename}.mp4`))
            .on('finish', callback);
    });

    // return filename; //try and get relative path
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write it like this:

```js
var downloadFile = (uri, filename) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.head(uri, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log('\n', 'Downloading File');
        request(uri)
            .on('error', error => {
                res.status(502).send(error.message)
                reject(error)
            })
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${filename}.mp4`))
            .on('finish', resolve);
    });
})
```

You don’t need `callback` parameter if you use promise, since it brings its own callbacks, `resolve` and `reject`. You don’t need `async` either cus its just syntax sugar to wrap a function’s return value into promise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply dude, appreciate ur time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you would like to know about is, with Node.js, to use "Streams" with Node.js and from Node.js module itself. As you tryed to do it.

Very short version to explain what is Streams is the way to split something (a file for you) and send it in a pipe to get asynchronousy part of the splited content without block anything or loose any data in case of communication cut.

So this is the official link to learn about  ["Streams" in Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn/nodejs-streams)
And here is the API documentation: [official Node.js Streams reference API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)